# delete button in REACTJS, how can I send a value via AXIOS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios, delete-row

I would like the variable "id" to contain the id of a book, in order to send it to the back via axios. it's a table containing several books with a delete button in each row, so the "id" must contain the book id of the line concerned. if anyone can help me please?
(Also, if someone can help me how can I edit the data of each book, in order to send them also via Axios?)

```
import React from 'react';
import { MDBTable, MDBTableBody, MDBTableHead, MDBCol, MDBBtn } from 'mdbreact';
import './mesLivres.css';
import axios from 'axios';

class MyBooks extends React.Component {

state = {
  loading: true,
  books: null,
  id: '',
  error: '',
};

change = async e => {
  await this.setState({
    id : e.target.value,
  });
}

handleSubmit = e => {

  console.log(this.state);
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("title",this.state.id);
  const url = "http://localhost:8888/API/affichage/supprimer.php"
  axios.post(url, formData)

  .then(function(response){
    console.log(response);
    alert('book has been deleted');
  })

  .catch((error)=>{
    if (error.response.status === 403){
      console.log(error);
      alert('no deleted');
    }
  });

  setTimeout(() => {
    this.setState({
      error: '',
    });
  }, 2000);

  e.preventDefault();
}


async componentDidMount() {
  const url = "http://localhost:8888/liste_livres/liste.php";
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const data = await response.json();
  this.setState({books: data.results.livres, loading: false})
  console.log(data.results.livres);
}


render() {
  if(this.state.loading){
    return <div>chargement...</div>;
  }

  if (!this.state.books){
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 className="myBibli"> Mes livres </h1>
        <div className="noBook">
          Vous n'avez actuellement aucun livre dans votre bibliothèque.
        </div>
      </div>  
    );
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="myBibli"> Mes livres </h1>
      <br></br>
      <h2> Vous avez {this.state.books.length} livres dans votre bibliothèque:</h2>
      <br></br>
      <MDBTable hover>
        <MDBTableHead>
          <tr>
            <th>Titre</th>
            <th>Auteur</th>
            <th>Année de sortie</th>
            <th>Edition</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Statut</th>
            <th>Date d'achat</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
        </MDBTableHead>
        <MDBTableBody>
          {
            this.state.books.map(livre => (
              <tr key={livre.id} onChange={this.Change} >
                <td>{livre.title} </td>
                <td>{livre.author}</td>
                <td>{livre.year}</td>
                <td>{livre.edition}</td>
                <td>{livre.typeBook}</td>
                <td>{livre.status}</td>
                <td>{livre.date}</td>
                <td><MDBBtn color="dark">Modifier</MDBBtn></td>
                <td><MDBBtn type="submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit} color="dark">Supprimer</MDBBtn></td>
              </tr>
            ))
          }
        </MDBTableBody>
      </MDBTable>

    </div>
  );
}
}

export default MyBooks;
```

Comment: Use `onClick={() => this.handleDelete(livre.id)}` for the delete button.

Comment: even if I change like this, this is not ok. do you have an idea of something else to change? I just want to sen the id book to my link "supprimer.php"

Comment: Besides having to use `handleSubmit` instead of `handleDelete`, how is my suggestion "not ok"? Do you see the request in the browser's console / network tab? You do also need to reload the list to actually remove the book client-side, which means you should move the `liste.php` code to a function `update()` and call that from `componentDidMount` and after deletion.

Comment: it works fine thank you very much!